# Repeating msgbox

Tags: vba, excel

I've created 3 combobox as below which are to generate results from a listbox. I would like to generate an error box if any of the 3 comboboxes are left empty. However, the code I wrote generates multiple error msg boxes. How do I fix this so msgbox only appears once?

```
Private Sub Generateresults_Click()
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim p As Integer
p = Sheets("Training1A").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Sheets("Results").Range("A2:P" & p).ClearContents
x = 2
For i = 0 To Me.Listtest.ListCount - 1
    If Me.Searchoption = "AND" Then
        If Me.Listtest.Column(1, i) = Search1 And Me.Listtest.Column(2, i) = Search2 Then
            For j = 0 To 9
                Sheets("results").Cells(x, j + 1) = Me.Listtest.Column(j, i)
            Next j
            x = x + 1
        Else
            x = x
        End If

        ElseIf Me.Searchoption = "OR" Then
            If Me.Listtest.Column(1, i) = Search1 Or Me.Listtest.Column(2, i) = Search2 Then
                For j = 0 To 9
                    Sheets("results").Cells(x, j + 1) = Me.Listtest.Column(j, i)
                Next j
                x = x + 1
            Else
                x = x
            End If

        ElseIf Me.Searchoption = "ALL" Then            
            For j = 0 To 9
                Sheets("results").Cells(x, j + 1) = Me.Listtest.Column(j, i)
            Next j
            x = x + 1
        Else
            x = x               
            **If Searchoption = "" Or Search1 = "" Or Search2 = "" Then
                MsgBox "Select an option"
            End If**
        End If         
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to bail out after dispaying the first `MsgBox`, put `Exit Sub` under it.

```
If Searchoption = "" Or Search1 = "" Or Search2 = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select an option"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Otherwise, the `MsgBox` call being inside the `For...Next` loop body, it will be repeated for every iteration that satisfies the conditions.

If you need to run more code between `Next` and `End Sub` regardless of whether the `MsgBox` was shown or not, then you can also `Exit For`, to exit the loop but remain inside the procedure:

```
If Searchoption = "" Or Search1 = "" Or Search2 = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select an option"
    Exit For
End If
```